# arduino wifi client not posting data to mysql server

Tags: mysql, arduino, wifi

data says it has been sent and is seen on the apache log but the actual data is not posted. I can post data via browser using the php script i wrote so i know the php script "project0" works. in a separate script that i wrote the data is actually posted to the server during the void setup period but only once. i have also configured mysql to allow remote users access to phpmyadmin.

apache log info from esp32: 192.168.1.10 - - [21/Mar/2021:03:03:37 -0400] "GET /stringcode/project0.php?names=Jonathon Allen" 400 325 "-" "-"

apache log info from successful data post from browser: ::1 - - [20/Mar/2021:23:01:37 -0400] "GET /stringcode/project0.php?names=jonathon allen HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/89.0.4389.90 Safari/537.36"

```
    #include <SPI.h>
    #include <MFRC522.h>
    #include <WiFi.h>

    #define RST_PIN   13
    #define SS_PIN    23
    #define WIFI_SSID "NETGEAR04"
    #define WIFI_PASSWORD "huskylotus321"

    MFRC522 mfrc522(SS_PIN,RST_PIN);
    WiFiClient client;

    String USERNAME = "";

    void setup() {
       Serial.begin(9600);
       while(!Serial);

       SPI.begin();
       mfrc522.PCD_Init();
       mfrc522.PCD_DumpVersionToSerial();

       WiFi.begin(WIFI_SSID, WIFI_PASSWORD);
       while(WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED){
       Serial.println(" Trying to connect to wifi.. ");
       delay(100);
         }
        Serial.println("connected to wifi...");
        Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
         Serial.println("Ready to scan...");
        }

        void loop() {
          if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_IsNewCardPresent()) {
          return;
           }
          if ( ! mfrc522.PICC_ReadCardSerial()) {
          return;
           }

          Serial.println("UID tag is : ");
          String content = "";
          byte letter;

              for (byte i = 0; i < mfrc522.uid.size; i++)         // to populate content with the 
              string characters read from MFRC522
              {
              Serial.print(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i] < 0x10 ? " 0" : " ");
              Serial.print(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i], HEX);        // print what contents value is on 
              content.concat(String(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i] < 0x10 ? " 0" : " "));
              content.concat(String(mfrc522.uid.uidByte[i], HEX));
              }

               Serial.println();
               Serial.println("Message : ");
               content.toUpperCase();  

              if(content.substring(1) == "37 07 04 D9" ){

              Serial.println(" Jonathon Allen ");
              USERNAME = "Jonathon Allen";
              Sending_to_MYSQL();
                 
              }
              if(content.substring(1) == "57 01 A2 C8" ){
              Serial.println("Elijah Anies");
              USERNAME = "Elijah Anies";
              Sending_to_MYSQL();

               }
              delay(100);
              }

              void Sending_to_MYSQL(){
              int    HTTP_PORT   = 80;
              String HTTP_METHOD = "GET"; // or "POST"
              char   HOST_NAME[] = "192.168.1.11"; // hostname of web server:
              String PATH_NAME   = "/stringcode/project0.php?names=";

              if(client.connect(HOST_NAME,HTTP_PORT)){
              Serial.println("connected to server but may have not successfully sent data ");

              client.println(HTTP_METHOD + " " + PATH_NAME + USERNAME + " HTTP/1.1");
              client.println("Host: " + String(HOST_NAME));
              client.println();

              } else{
               Serial.println("Did not connect to server ");
                   }

               if(client.connected())
               client.stop();

                 delay(500);
               }
```

Comment: spces in the data must be url encodet with %20 like **GET /stringcode/project0.php?names=Jonathon%20Allen HTTP/1.1**

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a shot.

Comment: why do you not direcly write to mysql ?

Comment: you are a life saver

Comment: because this is an attendance system which will be isolated from any ethernet connection from the host.

Comment: of course im not completely finished with it just yet